# Convert text to InnerHTML Value of a Button onClick on <input> tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, font-awesome

I want to change the Button' value with a font awesome spinning animation icon on click.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
<input id="button_g" type="button" class="button-default" value="Go" onclick="abc(this);">
```

**Script:**

```
function abc(this1)
{
  //alert('asdasd');
  this1.disabled=true; 
  this1.value ='<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>';

}
```

This one only replaces the Button's value with a non-working html code. I tried it with:

```
document.getElementById('button_g').innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>';
```

But doesn't work. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `input` you should use `button` and set `innerHTML` of `button`

```js
function abc(this1) {
  this1.disabled = true;
  this1.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>';

}
```

```css
button {
  padding: .25rem .75rem;
  border: 1px solid #3d3a37;
  border-radius: 6px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button id="button_g" class="button-default" onclick="abc(this);"> Go </button>
```

Comment: Is there a way for this to work on the `input` instead of using `button` ? My site was a predefined (Using Elementor) and is already using `input` instead of `button` tag.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, But you can show/hide the element as per your need

Comment: Yes! @decpk that would be the best solution, using dynamic classes to hide and show the elements

Comment: I found a way to convert it instead of hiding `var input = document.getElementById('button_g');

    input.outerHTML = input.outerHTML.replace(/^\<input/, '<button') + input.value + '</button>';`

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute has a different meaning for each type of the input tag. Yours is a button and so the value attribute is linked to the text inside the button, ***not*** the inner html of it.

If you want to change the inner html, use `this1.innerHtml`

For more read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp)